# Is it possible to multiply by -1 in a CRM Dynamics 2016 Workflow?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I'm trying to create a workflow that would make the target field value a negative number.  I want to create related records as credits and debits and then be able to sum them up to get a net value.

I've tried to update the field to -1 and then multiply it accordingly, but I get an error stating that the value needs to be between 0 and 1,000,000,000,000.  I've also just tried to multiply the value by a -1, but that doesn't work either. It just runs the workflow, but doesn't change the value.

Comment: Check in customization of the field, what is minimum value allowed in the field. You probably need to change it to -1.

Comment: The field does allow negative numbers, but the workflow doesn't when I try to update the entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured this one out.  I created two different workflows to create records in one entity with different "Types".  Then, on the account I had a rollup field to sum one type and then a rollup type to sum the other type.  Then I used a calculated field to subtract one from the other.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the comment from @MarioZG it looks like your CRM field doesn't allow negative numbers.

When you setup a number field (Decimal; Currency; Floating or Whole Number) you can specify the range of acceptable values. Here's a quick screenshot of the Whole Number's properties:

[image: Number Properties]

Answer (score 0):

Use data type of the field as decimal number(looking at your use), in this case you will have flexibility of storing all sort of numbers.